# Compute the largest product of 4 consecutive numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

Below I am taking a string of numbers, converting to a list, then I run a list comprehension taking the product of what is supposed to be the largest product of 4 consecutive numbers. But my code will just take 9^4 and I'm not exactly sure how to rectify it

```
hundred_digit_str= (
                    "731671765313306249192251"\
                    "196744265747423553491949349"\
                    "6983520312774506326239578318"\
                    "016984801869478851843"\
                   )
    hundred_digit_str = list(hundred_digit_str)
    result = max(int(a) * int(b) * int(c) *int(d) for a, b, c, d in zip(hundred_digit_str, hundred_digit_str, hundred_digit_str, hundred_digit_str[:]))
```

Comment: You need to zip displaced versions e.g. `zip(h, h[1:], h[2:], h[3:])` (where `h` is the long variable name I can't be bothered to type four times) - obviously this goes into your existing expression where you are already using zip.

Comment: Incidentally, there's no need to convert it into a list first.

Comment: Also incidentally, it's not a list comprehension. You are (sensibly) using a generator expression instead.

Comment: That worked thanks! I'll google the difference between the two :D